# array.map() does not render items horizontally in a grid container in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React and material-ui.
My goal is to render a grid container, starting from an external javascript file, that exports its own array. This grid must have 3 items per row, but at the moment it just renders the items on a single column.
Here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import CoffeeCard from "./CoffeeCard";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import files from "./constants";

function Content() {
  return (
    <Grid direction="rows" container spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
        {files.map((obj) => {
          return (
            <CoffeeCard
              title={obj.title}
              price={obj.price}
              description={obj.description}
              avatarUrl={obj.avatarUrl}
              imgSrc={obj.imgSrc}
            />
          );
        })}
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default Content;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the nested `Grid` component for individual items inside the map function. Right now your code is only rendering 1 `Grid` item component with children , you need to render one for each row:

```js
 <Grid direction="rows" container spacing={2}>
    {files.map((obj) => {
      return (
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
          <CoffeeCard
            title={obj.title}
            price={obj.price}
            description={obj.description}
            avatarUrl={obj.avatarUrl}
            imgSrc={obj.imgSrc}
          />
        </Grid>
      );
    })}
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is how you are using the `<Grid />` component from Material UI. Please refer to [its documentation on `Grid`](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/) for more info.

Notably, you want your `item` to wrap *each individual item*. As you have it, you have a single *item* that wraps your content.

So just move your `<Grid item>` into your `.map` return value:

```
import React from 'react';
import CoffeeCard from './CoffeeCard';
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import files from './constants';

function Content() {
  return (
    <Grid direction="rows" container spacing={2}>
      {files.map((obj) => {
        return (
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
            <CoffeeCard
              title={obj.title}
              price={obj.price}
              description={obj.description}
              avatarUrl={obj.avatarUrl}
              imgSrc={obj.imgSrc}
            />
          </Grid>
        );
      })}
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default Content;
```